# How can i scan an individual jar file using fortify?

Tags: java, jar, fortify

I have requirement to scan the jar file using fortify. I am using Fortify version 22.2. I added below properties as mentioned in the fortify documentation.

```
com.fortify.sca.fileextensions.class=BYTECODE
com.fortify.sca.fileextensions.jar=ARCHIVE
com.fortify.sca.DecompileBytecode=true
```

I tried to use some commands using source code analyzer which i found on stackoverflow but it did not work.

Would it be possible to scan individual jar file ? or does the jar file need to be part of a Java Project ?

Can ayone please advise ?